# C ERROR: Expression must have integral type (sin signal generator in ccs)

Tags: c

I want generate chirp signal using DSP.
But my coding file is generated error: expression must have integral type
I am using ezdsp5535.
In ccs4.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "ezdsp5535.h"

#include "math.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi (3.141593)
#define Fs (500000)
#define dt (1/Fs)
#define x (1500)
#pragma DATA_SECTION(y,"myOutput")

int Fat0=25000;
int FatA=15000; 
float TA=0.003;

void main( void )
{
    float t=0;
    double y[x];
    float X_ahp=(2*pi*(FatA-Fat0))/TA;
    float X_beta=2*pi*Fat0;
    int n;
    EZDSP5535_init( );
    for (n=0; n<=1500; n=t++)
    {
        t=t+dt;
        y[n]= sin(X_beta*t+X_ahp*(t^2)); // expression must have integral type (error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of t^2? Do you mean pow(t, 2)?

Comment: Please provide the exact error message and line number that it gives. FYI, the expression `t&2` in C means `t` exclusive OR'd with `2` (*i.e.*, `t XOR 2`). Please consult your C math library documentation.

Comment: xor a floating point is senseless.

Comment: note: `dt` is `0` since `1` and `500000` are both `int`, the result of a binary operation on them is also an `int`. You probably meant `#define dt (1.0/Fs)`. However using this the way you use it is very inaccurate (little inaccuracy will accumulate every iteration), it would be better to use something like `t = 1.0 * n / Fs;` instead

Comment: your `include`s are weird too

Comment: The loop should be `for (n = 0; n < 1500; n++)`.  As you wrote it, there is a buffer overflow, and nonsense in the last part.

Answer (score 4):

```
y[n]= sin(X_beta*t+X_ahp*(t^2));
```

You must think `t^2` means the power 2 of `t`. It's not. `^` is the bitwise xor operator. You can use `pow` function instead.

As @Matt McNabb points out, for the power of 2, you can use `t * t` here.

Comment: `t*t` is probably better than `pow` here

Answer (score 1):

The `^`  (binary xor) operator is not defined for floats while using it in `t^2`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979.aspx says: "Both operands to the bitwise exclusive OR operator must be of integral types. "